# Error while installing Force.com BETA IDE plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am not able to find problem while creating project in eclipes. I am trying to add project as shown in picture[image]

[image]

please let me know what could be the problem. I am doing this in my office.

Comment: i am sorry not while creating project, while plugin force.com IDE in to eclipes.

Comment: try this link "http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42" or use

http://mavensmate.com/